# dynamically updated stored procedure in Tableau?

Tags: stored-procedures, tableau-api

I want to create a Tableau dashboard which has a stored procedure as a data source. The SP takes parameters, including a date. I can do this manually, but not dynamically.

Use case: publish to Tableau server with a weekly refresh, which means a new date every time you call the SP.

Has anyone done this? I see some info on it, but it doesn't mention how to do dynamically.

https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/connect_basic_stored_procedures.htm

Comment: It sounds like the parameter is going to be for a specific date, like "yesterday" or "last week" and you want Tableau to dynamically pass in that date value. Instead, could you build an SP without a parameter and have the SP itself deduce what the date is that you would have passed in?

Comment: Yeah that might be the best (only) approach. I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on size constraints, consider looping through all values of the parameters, and building a table that stores the result set for each combination of parameter values. Set that 'history' table as your data source, rather than the stored procedure